# Figure dimensions, matplotlib, python3.4

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fig1():
    x = np.arange(-5,5,0.01)
    f1 = lambda x: x**2 +x -6
    f2 = lambda x: x*0
    plt.plot(x, f1(x))
    plt.plot(x, f2(x),'black')
    axes = plt.gca()
    axes.set_ylim([-10,10])
    axes.set_xlim([-5,5])
    plt.show()
```

[image]
How can I force this figure into specific dimensions? At the moment it is displayed on a rectangular plane, but I want to force the dimensions to be strictly n x n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to force a `pyplot` to a manually specified size, it can be done so by using the `figsize` parameter from the [**`matplotlib.figure` module**](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html)

The example of two sizes, one rectangle and one square of dimensions `5x5 and 5x8` here in the below example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fig1():
    x = np.arange(-5,5,0.01)
    f1 = lambda x: x**2 +x -6
    f2 = lambda x: x*0
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,8)) # IT IS HERE THAT WE SPECIFY THE FIGSIZE
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(x, f1(x))
    ax.plot(x, f2(x),'black')
    ax.set_ylim([-10,10])
    ax.set_xlim([-5,5])
    plt.show()
```

**when we use `5x5` we get something like this**:
[image]

**and when we use `5x8` we get something like this:**

[image]